Lagrange mutiplier with multivariable function and constraint
As title suggests, I need to optimize a multivariable function with a constraint, specifically;
$$f(x,y,z)=z^2e^{xy}, \text{w/ constraint S: } x^2+y^2+z^2≤1$$
clearly one st. pt. will be on the plane $(x,y,0)$
setting up lagrange:
$$\begin{cases}
yz^2e^{xy}=\lambda(2x)\\
xz^2e^{xy}=\lambda(2y)\\
2ze^{xy}=\lambda(2z)\\
x^2+y^2+z^2=1
\end{cases} $$
My professor's solutions claims that

here one uses the lagrange multiplier method and finds the possible extrema pts. $$ (\pm1,0,0,1),(0,\pm1,0,1),(0,0,\pm1,1),(x,y,0,0) \text{ in the last case where } x^2+y^2=1$$
the st. pts. of f on S are $(x,y,0)$ with $x^2+y^2=1$ and $(0,0,\pm 1)$ we already saw that the pts. $(x,y,0)$ with $x^2+y^2\le 1$ are global min. pts. for f on S. The points $(0,0,\pm1)$ are global max. pts. for f on S

No matter how many times I try, I don't understand how he derived those pts. using the lagrange method. For every problem with two variables and a constraint, I have been able to solve the extrema with lagrange, but basically every 3 variable problem gets me stuck. What am I doing wrong? And how did my professor derive those pts?

Here is an imgur link (https://imgur.com/a/KEilTg7) which shows my work and my professor's notes for extra context.

If you assume $z\neq 0$ then the third LM equation gives $e^{xy}=\lambda$, which can be used to simplify the first two equations.

The points $(\pm1,0,0,1)$ and $(0,\pm 1,0,1)$ do not satisfy the first and the second equation, respectively.

We have:
$yz^2e^{xy}=\lambda(2x)\\
xz^2e^{xy}=\lambda(2y)\\
2ze^{xy}=\lambda(2z)\\
x^2+y^2+z^2=1$
What can we do to cancel out the $e^{xy}$ factor from the first 3 equations?
$xyz^2e^{xy} = 2\lambda x^2\\
xyz^2e^{xy} = 2\lambda y^2\\
xyz^2e^{xy} = \lambda xyz$
$2\lambda x^2 = 2\lambda y^2$
$\lambda = 0$ or $x= y$ or $x=-y$
If $\lambda = 0$ then $x = 0$ and $y = 0$ or $z = 0$
$f(0,0,\pm 1) = 1\\
f(x,y,0) = 0$
If $x = \pm y$ then $2\lambda x^2 = \pm \lambda x^2z$ and $z=2$
But, this is contradictory to the constraint.

So do you have both the minimization and maximization problem having the same Lagrange multiplier (a value of $\lambda = 0$)? I understand why $\lambda = 0$ for the minimization (the constraint has no affect on the minimizer of the objective function based on how the objective function is constructed; it is nonnegative). But I do not quite follow how $\lambda$ could be zero for the maximization problem, as the constraint directly affects where the maximizer occurs. My apologies if this this an unclear question.

Define $$f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} : (x,y,z) \mapsto z^2 e^{xy}$$ and $$g : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} : \mathbf{x} = (x,y,z) \mapsto x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1 = \|\mathbf{x}\|^2_{2} - 1.$$ One problem is to
\begin{align}
\textrm{Minimize} ~ f(\mathbf{x}) ~ \textrm{subject to}~ g(\mathbf{x}) \leq 0 ~\textrm{for}~ \mathbf{x} = (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3.
\end{align}
Let $\mathbf{x}_{*}$ be a solution to the above problem. The multiplier rule states that there exists $(\eta, \lambda) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies the following:

$\textbf{Nontriviality Condition}:$ $(\eta, \lambda) \neq (0,0).$
$\textbf{Positivity Condition}:$ $\eta = 0$ (abnormal case) or $\eta = 1$ (normal case), and $\lambda \geq 0;$
$\textbf{Complementary Slackness Condition}:$ $\lambda g(\mathbf{x}_{*}) = 0.$
$\textbf{Stationarity Condition}:$ $\eta \nabla f(\mathbf{x}_{*}) + \lambda 
\nabla g(\mathbf{x}_{*}) = (0,0,0).$

The first step, typically, is to check which case we are in for $\eta.$ For the abnormal case, $\eta = 0.$ If $\eta = 0,$ then the necessary conditions imply that $\nabla g(\mathbf{x}_{*}) = 0$ which further implies that $$2(x,y,z) = (0,0,0) \iff \mathbf{x}_{*} = (x_{*}, y_{*}, z_{*}) = (0,0,0).$$ Note that this is, indeed, a global minimizer by inspection, since $z^2 e^{x y} \geq 0$ for all $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3.$ However, this solution would require $\lambda = 0,$ which violates nontriviality, so we must be in the normal case. Furthermore, any $\mathbf{x}_{*} = (x_{*}, y_{*}, 0) \in \{ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3 \, | \, \| \mathbf{x} \|_{2} \leq 1 \}$ would suffice. To properly do this portion of the problem, we would have to set $\eta = 1$ and solve the problem using the conventional steps. We forgo this additional work, as it would yield $\mathbf{x}_{*} = (x_{*}, y_{*}, 0)$ with $x_{*}$ and $y_{*}$ being arbitrary real numbers such that $x^{2}_{*} + y^{2}_{*} \leq 1$ and $\lambda = 0.$
Another problem is to
\begin{align}
\textrm{Minimize} ~ h(\mathbf{x}) \triangleq -f(\mathbf{x}) ~ \textrm{subject to}~ g(\mathbf{x}) \leq 0 ~\textrm{for}~ \mathbf{x} = (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3
\end{align}
(this is our maximization problem).
It is clear that we are in the normal case (the abnormal case yields an answer that is nonsensical: $\mathbf{x} = 0_{\mathbb{R}^3}$ which we know is not a maximizer of $f$), so take $\eta = 1.$ Let $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3.$ Since
\begin{align}
\nabla h(\mathbf{x}) = \begin{bmatrix} -y z^2 e^{xy} \\ -x z^2 e^{x y} \\ -2 z e^{x y} \end{bmatrix} ~~\textrm{and}~~ \nabla g(\mathbf{x}) = 2 \mathbf{x} = 2 \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix},
\end{align}
the stationarity condition is
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix} - y_{*} z^2_{*} e^{x_{*}y_{*}} \\ - x_{*} z^2_{*} e^{x_{*} y_{*}} \\ - 2 z_{*} e^{x_{*} y_{*}} \end{bmatrix} = - 2 \lambda \begin{bmatrix} x_{*} \\ y_{*} \\ z_{*} \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
This implies the following:

$y_{*} z^2_{*} e^{x_{*}y_{*}} - 2 \lambda x_{*} = 0;$
$x_{*} z^2_{*} e^{x_{*}y_{*}} - 2 \lambda y_{*} = 0;$
$z_{*}(e^{x_{*} y_{*}} - \lambda) = 0 \iff z_{*} = 0$ or $\lambda = e^{x_{*} y_{*}}.$

It is clear that $z_{*} \neq 0.$  Hence, $\lambda = e^{x_{*} y_{*}} > 0.$ In turn

$y_{*} z^2_{*} e^{x_{*}y_{*}} - 2 x_{*} e^{x_{*} y_{*}} = e^{x_{*} y_{*}} (y_{*} z^2_{*} - 2 x_{*}) = 0 \Rightarrow x_{*} = (1/2) y_{*} z^2_{*};$
$x_{*} z^2_{*} e^{x_{*}y_{*}} - 2 y_{*} e^{x_{*} y_{*}} = e^{x_{*} y_{*}}(x_{*} z^2_{*} - 2 y_{*}) = 0 \Rightarrow y_{*} = (1/2) x_{*} z^2_{*}.$

By plugging $y_{*} = (1/2) x_{*} z^2_{*}$ into $x_{*} = (1/2) y_{*} z^2_{*},$ we have
\begin{align}
x_{*} = (1/4) x_{*} z^4_{*} &\iff x_{*}(1 - (1/4) z^4_{*}) = 0 \\
&\iff x_{*} = 0 ~\textrm{or}~ z_{*} = 2^{1/2}.
\end{align}

If $x_{*} = 0,$ then $y_{*} = 0$ and
\begin{align}
\boxed{h(\mathbf{x}_{*}) = - f(\mathbf{x}_{*}) = -z^{2}_{*}}.
\end{align}
Hence, $\boxed{\lambda = e^{0} =  1}$ and $\boxed{z_{*} \in \{ 1, - 1\}}$ when taking into account complementary slackness:
\begin{align}
\lambda g(\mathbf{x}_{*}) = 0 &\iff e^{x_{*} y_{*}} ( x^{2}_{*} + y^{2}_{*} + z^{2}_{*} - 1 ) = 0 \\
&\iff e^{x_{*} y_{*}} ( z^{2}_{*} - 1 ) = 0 \\
&\iff z^{2}_{*} = 1 \\
&\iff z_{*} \in \{-1, 1 \}.
\end{align}
If $x_{*} \neq 0,$ then $y_{*} = x_{*} $ and with the complementary slackness condition, we must have
\begin{align}
\lambda g(\mathbf{x}_{*}) = 0 &\iff e^{x^{2}_{*}}(x^{2}_{*} + x^{2}_{*} + \sqrt{2} - 1) = 0 \\
&\iff 2 x^{2}_{*} = 1 - \sqrt{2} \\
&\iff x_{*} = \sqrt{\frac{ 1 - \sqrt{2} }{ 2 }}.
\end{align}
Thus,
\begin{align}
y_{*} = x_{*} = \sqrt{\frac{ 1 - \sqrt{2} }{ 2 }}.
\end{align}
This would imply that $\mathbf{x}_{*} = \left( \sqrt{\frac{ 1 - \sqrt{2} }{ 2 }}, \sqrt{\frac{ 1 - \sqrt{2} }{ 2 }}, 2^{1/4} \right) \in \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{R},$ which cannot hold.

All together, $f(\mathbf{x}_{*})$ is maximized for $$ \boxed{\mathbf{x}_{*} \in \{ (0,0,-1), (0,0,1) \}} $$
with Lagrange multiplier $\boxed{\lambda = 1}$ and multiplier $\boxed{(\eta, \lambda) = (1,1)}.$
